# Application Working day before not working now

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

My project was working day before yesterday, but its not working anymore strangely.

I have not made any changes to code. The webpage keeps giving an error `webdev.webserver40.exe has stopped working` error. Here is my website code:

```
    <%@ Page Title="Loading..." Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="~/Loading.aspx.cs" Inherits="memberlogin.Loading" %>


<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout('Redirect()',4000);
function Redirect()
{
  location.href = 'Members.aspx';
}
</script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 80%;
            background-image: url('Images/loading.gif');
            height: 100%;
        }
        .bg
        {
            width: 960px ;
            height: auto;
            background-image: url('Images/clouds.jpg');
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" >
    <h1>
        <span class="input">Members-only page.</span>
    </h1>
    <h2>
        Client Side Application Download Started.
    </h2>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <table class="style1">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="middle">
            <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        Loading, Please wait...<br />
                        <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <br />

</asp:Content>
```

I put a try catch block to understand what is the error. This is the Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace memberlogin
{
    public partial class Loading : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(Launcher));
            t.Start();
        }

        public void Launcher()
        {

            try
            {
                string filename = "~/Downloads/User.exe";
                WebClient req = new WebClient();
                HttpResponse Response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + Server.MapPath(filename) + "\"");
                byte[] data = req.DownloadData(Server.MapPath(filename));
                Response.BinaryWrite(data);
                Response.End();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.Message + e.Source);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I now get this error:
[image]

`MemberLogin` is the name of my project. I need to submit this by morning [its night where i am], i need to also do documentation please help me out. I have around 6 hours and not more.

Comment: What line is throwing that error?

Comment: I get that exception most probably due to `Response`... i was playing around with the code, now i get this error `Response is not available in this context`

Comment: To me it sounds like a threading issue in ASP.NET.  Does an iisreset help the first time? You could also try to put a `t.IsBackground = true;` before starting the new thread.

Comment: try to end task your webdev server on taskmanger and try to clean,build you app then run again your application.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to try to pinpoint where the exception is being thrown is to turn on first chance exceptions:

In Visual Studio:

Debug > Exceptions > CLR Exceptions > Thrown (checked)

Any time an exception is thrown the debugger will break.